# Is there a standard way of locating a package's config files?

Tags: package-management, rpm, documentation

Just curious if there is a standard way of locating where a package puts the config files for a program (assuming the documentation for the package doesn't include this information).

The reason way I ask is because I was trying to install flow-tools on centos. There isn't a package in any repositories and I was frustrated building it from source because I couldn't find where it put the config file.

From what I have read online, installed with apt-get the config is apparently here `/etc/flow-tools/flow-capture.conf`. This file wasn't created when I used make to install the package on centos.

So following [what this guy](https://titdara.wordpress.com/2010/12/20/install-netflow-on-centos/) did I downloaded an rpm most relevant for my release and installed it:

```
sudo wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/flow-tools-0.68.5.1-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
rpm -Uvh flow-tools-0.68.5.1-1.el6.x86_64.rpm --nodeps
yum install flow-tools
```

Later in his little how to he edits the configuration file for the installed flow-tools which is located here: `/etc/sysconfig/flow-capture`

How did he know that's where the config file is? I was not able to locate this information myself for both the package I downloaded and the source files installed with make.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use rpm's query command with the configfiles option:

```
rpm -qc flow-tools
```

Comment: This worked great. Now should I expect all rpm packages to support this or will I often find packages that don't make their config file known in this way?

Comment: I can't speak for every package; the configfiles query option uses the information provided by the spec file's %config directive, so if the package builder provides that information, you can query it.

Comment: But in your experience is it usually available or do you run across packages that weren't setup this way?

Comment: For what it's worth, of the 756 packages installed on a randomly-chosen system I manage (a RHEL 6 "Basic Server"), 183 packages had configfiles defined (573 did not).

Answer (score 3):

For any `.rpm` file, run `rpm -qlp youpakage.rpm`. So for your rpm file, run

```
rpm -qlp flow-tools-0.68.5.1-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

or

```
rpm -qlp http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/flow-tools-0.68.5.1-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

and you'll see `/etc/sysconfig/flow-capture` in the list.

From `man rpm`

> -q -- query
>
> -p, --package PACKAGE_FILE
>                 Query  an  (uninstalled) package PACKAGE_FILE.  The PACKAGE_FILE may be specified as an ftp or http style URL, in which
>   case the package header
>                 will be downloaded and queried.  See FTP/HTTP OPTIONS for information on rpm’s internal ftp and http client  support.  The 
>   PACKAGE_FILE  argu-
>                 ment(s),  if not a binary package, will be interpreted as an ASCII package manifest unless --nomanifest option is used.  In
>   manifests, comments
>                 are permitted, starting with a ’#’, and each line of a package manifest file may include white  space  separated  glob 
>   expressions,  including
>                 URL’s,  that will be expanded to paths that are substituted in place of the package manifest as additional
>   PACKAGE_FILE arguments to the query.
>
> -l, --list
>                 List files in package.